# javafx set background image of a tab Content

Tags: java, javafx

how can i set an image as a the background for the content of this tab, so that I change that color to an image.

[image]

I tried this but it set the header not the content background

```
Tab tabSavings = new Tab();
tabSavings.getStyleClass().add("tab-debt");
tabSavings.setContent(createSavingsTab());
```

css

```
tab-debt{
-fx-background-image: url("04.jpg");}
```

[image]
 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

createSavingsTab() returns a ScrollPane, I just set FitToHeight to true and now it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the `TabPane` is filling the entire area, you can do

```
.tab-debt {
  -fx-background-image: url("04.jpg");
  -fx-background-size: cover ;
}
```

or `-fx-background-size: stretch ;`, depending on the exact effect you want.

Then just set the style class on the tab content, instead of the tab:

```
Tab tabSavings = new Tab();
Node content = createSavingsTab();
content.getStyleClass().add("tab-debt");
tabSavings.setContent(content);
```